# Are the Rationals under addition isomorphic to any set of numbers?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

I've proved that ($\mathbb {Q}$ , +) is not isomorphic to ($\mathbb {Z}$ , +) as part of an assignment:

Let $f : \mathbb {Q} \rightarrow \mathbb {Z}$  and $a = f(1)$, then
$a=f({1\over2}+{1\over2})=2f({1\over2})=3f({1\over3})=...$ and so on. Hence $\forall_{n\in\mathbb {Z}}$ $n$ divides $a$. Therefore, $a=0$ and so $f(n)=nf(1)=na=0$ $\forall_{n\in\mathbb {Z}}$ and so $f$ is clearly not a bijection.

And so I've been wondering if that same logic could apply to ($\mathbb {Q}$ , +) and any other group? Is there something that makes ($\mathbb {Z}$ , +) special here?

Comment: Your title question is odd: Every rational number *is* a number, so the rationals under addition *are* a set of numbers. So it's not really clear to me what you are asking. Also, your formula $f : \mathbb Q \to \mathbb R$ should probably be $f : \mathbb Q \to \mathbb Z$.

Comment: If you map $q$ to $a^q$, you get an isomorphism from $(\mathbb{Q},+)$ to a subset of $(\mathbb{R},\times)$

Comment: @MichaelHartley Seems appropriate as an answer.

Comment: Your argument does about $a$ does not apply to $0$ or any negative integer, so saying you have prove that "for every $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, $n$ divides $a$" is incorrect. Morever, *every* real number is divisible by *every* nonzero real number, so your conclusion that $a=0$ is utterly unwarranted.

Comment: Could I just point out that you have used the ambiguous word "any" twice. I suspect it is intended to mean "some" rather than "all" but it is linguistically completely unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there something that makes ($\mathbb {Z}$ , +) special here?

More like there's something special about $\mathbb{Q}$ here, namely that it is a [divisible group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisible_group) while $\mathbb{Z}$ is not. You've pretty much said that yourself in the proof.

Being divisible is an algebraic invariant, meaning that if there is an isomorphism $G\to H$ then $G$ is divisible if and only if $H$ is.

> And so I've been wondering if that same logic could apply to ($\mathbb {Q}$ , +) and any other group?

Any other group? Clearly not, the property you've used is as I said that $\mathbb{Q}$ is divisible while $\mathbb{Z}$ is not. There are other examples of groups that are divisible and isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$, e.g. $r\mathbb{Q}=\{r\cdot q\ |\ q\in\mathbb{Q}\}$ for any irrational $r\in\mathbb{R}$.

On the other hand not all divisible groups are isomorphic, e.g. $\mathbb{Q}^2$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$ while both are divisible. A counterexample with numbers arises naturally from the above by embedding $\mathbb{Q}^2$ into $\mathbb{R}$, for example by considering $\mathbb{Q}+\pi\mathbb{Q}=\{q+\pi p\ |\ q,p\in\mathbb{Q}\}$ group or even $\mathbb{R}$ itself (although the last one is of higher cardinality).

Answer (score 2):

For any positive irrational number $\alpha$, $\Bbb Q \cong \alpha \Bbb Q$ as additive groups under the obvious isomorphism $f(r)=\alpha r$.  You may find it useful practice to prove that $f$ is in fact an isomorphism of additive groups.